# How to get current user from sails into an angular view

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I have gotten a list of users from my sails back end into an angular view using $http. However, all I need is the information of the current user, and I need to access each attribute individually. Can someone provide for me an example of how I might go about this?

Comment: maybe this will help:
[Sail user from angular state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107715/sails-js-passport-js-getting-current-logged-in-user)

Comment: I kind of understand what is going on here (I'm very new to web apps and frameworks). But I'm not sure what '/get_user' and '/status_update' are. Are they functions in a sails controller? If so, how does it know which controller, and what is '/status_update' supposed to do?

Comment: My guess is that they are routes on sails used to access current logged in user on Sail. I have used angular a lot but haven't used Sail before

Comment: Well, below the block of code he defines "get_user" as a function which is what made me think it's in a controller. I've used sails minimally but am pretty new to all of this.

Comment: i see what you mean, `sailsSocket.get(
    '/get_user', {}, function(response){ callback}` from this link you can see clearly that sailSocket.get() makes a request to get_user and handle the response. anyway hope this helps you to solve your problem. have you been able to fix it?

Comment: No, sadly. Lots of trial and error.

Comment: From my understanding, you need to defined SailJS route for `get_user` `get_user: function(req, res) {
    if ( !req.isAuthenticated() ) return res.forbidden();

    return res.json({user: req.user});
}` see http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Routes and from Routes callback req parameter, you can get the user via `return res.json({user: req.user});`

Comment: Thanks for responding again. I got it on Friday, but I forgot to post the answer. I had to wait until today to post a formal answer.

Comment: great, hope this helps me one day if i end up using SailJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In api/controllers/UserController.js. This sails function returns the current user information in req.user.

```
   module.exports = {
     getUser: function(req,res) {
       return res.send(req.user);
};
```

In config/routes.js. This is the route to the 'getUser' function in UserController.js.

```
'/getUser': {
   controller: 'UserController',
   action: 'getUser'
}
```

In assets/js/controllers.js, here is the $http request to the 'getUser' function in UserController.js. This is how you get the information from req.user into the front end.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://localhost:1337/user/getUser").then(function(result) { 
     $scope.currentUser = result.data;
  })
}]);
```

In assets/js/app.js, make sure your angular route is set to your view.

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view', {templateUrl: 'partials/view.html', controller: 'myCtrl'});
}]);
```

After putting this code (with your own variables/routes/server info) in the correct places, you can access the current user in your view like this

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   {{ currentUser.email }} <br>
   {{ currentUser.username }} <br>
   {{ currentUser.etc }}
 </div>
```

I searched the internet high and low for a week for an answer on how to do this and eventually came up with this. I see that a lot of people (on this site especially) have asked the same question, and I never really found a good, explicit answer. So I thought I would post what I've come up with as an answer to my own question.